# How to draw a nXn metric or Grid over a surface View

Tags: android, bitmap, surfaceview, android-canvas

How to Draw a nXn Metric Over an Surface View. my Surface View Has an Image which has zoom effects and Pan(Drag). So how can I draw a nXn metric over that Surface View.
Pls Help not getting any idea from any tutorials.

Comment: What do you mean by metric? A grid?

Comment: yes a metric means a Grid. But not android widget.